# Function inpaint "was not declare in this scope"

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use the `inpaint` function in opencv, but I'm getting this error

```
loadimg.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
loadimg.cpp:19:28: error: 'INPAINT_TELEA' is not a member of 'cv'
loadimg.cpp:19:45: error: 'inpaint' was not declared in this scope
```

From typing this:

```
C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\prova>g++ -I"C:\opencv\build\include" 
 -L"C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib" loadimg.cpp -lopencv_core245 -lopencv_highgui245 
 -lopencv_img proc245 -o loadimg
```

This is my code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    Mat src = cv::imread("prova.jpg");
    Mat mask;
    cvtColor(src, mask, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    threshold(mask, mask, 220, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    Mat dst;
    inpaint(src, mask, dst, 1, cv::INPAINT_TELEA);
    imshow("image", dst);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cv::inpaint()` is declared in the `photo` module. You need to `#include <opencv2/photo/photo.hpp>` . Alternatively, you could `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`, which includes all of OpenCV's functionality.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
inpaint(src, mask, dst, 1, INPAINT_TELEA);
```

Also, include :opencv2/photo/photo.hpp